# how to create soap message

Tags: iphone

I am doing with soap request/response app. I have login page.That have user id and password. This is my soap message.

```
                         NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<SignOn xmlns=\"http://10.12.50.99/CUTechWebservices/CuTechWebService.asmx\">\n"

                         "<DeviceID>4A6B740C-0B5B-5F8C-8694-1EC0196C1C67</DeviceID>\n"
                         "<UserID>string</UserID>\n"
                         "<CrID>6</CrID>\n"
                         "<UserPin>string</UserPin>\n"
                         "</SignOn>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"];
```

As user id and password are diff for users, I want to pass the values from the textfields (user id and password) to the soap message.

How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So below is some steps to follow. I am not sure exact code you can use or not. But modify it as per your need.

For Calling Request Do something like this :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [WebAPIRequest buildSOAPRequest:@"WebserviceURL" withPostData:strRequest WebMethod:@"YourWebMethodHereForExample-ValidateUSer"];
Connection *con = [[[Connection alloc]initWithClass:@"getClientResult" withRoot:@"soap:Body" withDelegate:delegate withTag:tag]autorelease];
[[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:con] autorelease];
```

BuildDataRequest should be like this.

```
+(NSMutableURLRequest *)buildSOAPRequest:(NSString *)serviceUrl withPostData:(NSString *)dataString WebMethod:(NSString*)strMethod{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serviceUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [dataString length]];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
if (isRegion==YES)
{
    isRegion = NO;
    [theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",NSLocalizedString(@"SOAP Action1",nil),strMethod] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

}else 
{
    [theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",NSLocalizedString(@"SOAP Action",nil),strMethod] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
}

[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"%@",dataString);

return theRequest;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: But how will i put this strRequest object in the soapMessage.I have edited the que. Look at it again.

Comment: I modified my answer. Look in to that. Hope that help.